# If $\vec F$ is a solenoidal field, then curl curl curl $\vec F$=?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

**Question**:If $\vec F$ is a solenoidal field, then curl curl curl  $\vec F$=

a)$\nabla^4\vec F$

b)$\nabla^3\vec F$

c)$\nabla^2\vec F$

d) none of these.

**My approach**:I first calculate $\nabla×\nabla×\vec F$. We know that $$\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\textbf{F}\right)=\nabla\left(\nabla\cdot\textbf{F}\right)-\nabla^2\textbf{F}$$
and since $\vec F$ is solenoidal,$\nabla\cdot\textbf{F}=0$,there fore we have $$\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\textbf{F}\right)=-\nabla^2\textbf{F}$$
Now for $\nabla×\nabla×\nabla×\vec F$ I am unable to proceed,and totally stuck how to proceed further!I guess the answer is (b) but I have no idea.

Please guide me with correct answer!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please define what is meant by a "Solenoidal field"?

Comment: @Enforce "Solenoidal" is a somewhat common alternative term for "divergence free".

Comment: What are $\nabla^k$ when $k>2$?

Comment: @arthur would you like to give any hint?

Comment: If $\nabla \cdot \vec F=0$ and $\vec F$ is sufficiently smooth, then $\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec F=-\nabla^2 \vec F$ and $$\nabla \times \nabla \times \nabla \times \vec F =-\nabla \times \nabla^2 \vec F= -\nabla^2 \nabla \times \vec F$$What are the definitions of $\nabla^3$ and $\nabla^4$??

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to check an example. $F=(\cos y, \sin x,0)$ is divergence free. As you have shown, the second curl is a laplacian, and $-\nabla^2F=F$.
So the third curl only has $z$ component.

Now it is time to Interpret Notation. If $\nabla^3$ means gradient of laplacian then it gives a matrix so definitely wrong. If $\nabla^4$ is the bilaplacian, then it has no third component. So it’s none of them.

If $\nabla^k$ means the tensor of all $k$th derivatives (Max’s definition) then they all have the wrong shape ($ (\nabla\times)^3F$ is a vector).

And if you really mean $\nabla^k=\sum_i\partial_i^k$ (Notation that I have never seen before...) then again it’s all wrong because the third component of $\nabla^kF$ is always zero.

Comment: $\nabla^3,\nabla^4...\nabla^k$ has their usual meaning,....would you please elaborate more?

Comment: For example,when I say $\nabla^3\vec F$, I simply means $(\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3}+\frac{\partial^3}{\partial y^3}+\frac{\partial^3}{\partial z^3})(F_1i+F_2j+F_3k)$ ,where $F_1,F_2,F_3$ are components of field $\vec F$

Comment: @lbs One has to be a bit careful as "usual meaning" here can be  ambiguous: For example, I would intuitively consider $\nabla^k \vec F$ to be the set (or tensor) containing all $k$-th partial derivatives of $\vec F$ :)

Comment: @maxmillion janisch I hope it's quite clear after my comment!

Comment: @maxmillion What do you say now, what is correct answer?

Comment: @calvinKhor Why are you restricting $\vec F$ such that $F_z\equiv 0$??  This is completely unnecessary.  If $\nabla \cdot \vec F=0$ and $\vec F$ is sufficiently smooth, then $\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec F=-\nabla^2 \vec F$ and $$\nabla \times \nabla \times \nabla \times \vec F =-\nabla \times \nabla^2 \vec F= -\nabla^2 \nabla \times \vec F$$

Comment: @mark viola I did the same but did not reach any conclusion

Comment: @Ibs How are $\nabla^3$ and $\nabla^4$ defined?

Comment: @mark viola see my second comment in this comment section

Comment: @MarkViola because the choices are laid out for you, you do not need to prove a general result. If it fails for my choice of $F$, that is enough. And for planar $F$ it is clear that the curl only has $z$ component without calculation, giving the result

Comment: @calvin khor I think you are right, initially I thought that the operators $\nabla^3$ and $\nabla^4$ are very trivial but now I realise that I must be first clear with the definitions of these operators.Unfotunatly I can't say about these operators,this Question was asked in a examination,and they do not provide any additional information about these operators